# How do I write a function (analogous to a SAS macro) in R to import and format a list of Excel files?

Tags: r, function, macros

I'm looking for a more efficient way to write the following:

Read in all my Excel files

```
DF1 <- read_excel(DF1, sheet = "ABC", range = cell_cols(1:10) )
DF2 <- read_excel(DF2, sheet = "ABC", range = cell_cols(1:10) )
etc...
DF50 <- read_excel(DF50, sheet = "ABC", range = cell_cols(1:10) )
```

Add a column to each DF with a location

```
DF1$Location <- location1
DF2$Location <- location2
etc...
DF50$Location <- location50
```

Keep only columns with specified names, get rid of blank rows, and convert column CR_NUMBER to an integer

```
library(hablar)
DF1 <- DF1 %>% select(all_of(colnames_r)) %>% filter(!is.na(NAME)) %>% convert(int(CR_NUMBER))
DF2 <- DF2 %>% select(all_of(colnames_r)) %>% filter(!is.na(NAME)) %>% convert(int(CR_NUMBER))
etc...
DF50 <- DF50 %>% select(all_of(colnames_r)) %>% filter(!is.na(NAME)) %>% convert(int(CR_NUMBER))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use the following getting the data in a list :

```
library(readxl)
library(hablar)
library(dplyr)

#Get the complete path of file which has name "DF" followed by a number.
file_names <- list.files('/folder/path', pattern = 'DF\\d+', full.names = TRUE)

list_data <- lapply(seq_along(file_names), function(x) {
  data <- read_excel(file_names[x], sheet = "ABC", range = cell_cols(1:10))
  data %>%
    mutate(Location = paste0('location', x))
    select(all_of(colnames_r)) %>% 
    filter(!is.na(NAME)) %>% 
    convert(int(CR_NUMBER))
})
```

`list_data` is a list of dataframes which is usually better to manage instead of having 50 dataframes in global environment. If you still want all the dataframes separately name the list and use `list2env`.

```
names(list_data) <- paste0('DF', seq_along(list_data))
list2env(list_data, .GlobalEnv)
```